# Lambda/Sort Summariser Issue - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I am using Thavelick's summarizer with some edits and cannot find a way to fix this error:

> TypeError: < lambda > () missing 1 required positional argument: 's2'

Here is the code I know is causing the error:

```
def reorder(input, output):
    output.sort(key=lambda s1, s2: input.find(s1)-input.find(s2))
    return output
```

Thavelick's summarizer link: https://github.com/thavelick/summarize/blob/master/summarize.py

Comment: Please give an example of what each variable is, including `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: @JakeMorris thats exactly what I am thinking too. It was from this gitHub repository https://github.com/thavelick/summarize/blob/master/summarize.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code probably use the `cmp` argument for `sort` which is gone now. You cannot just use the same `lamdba`. The `key` function must accept only one argument.

There is a way to blindly convert the code: use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key). However I believe in this case it is easier to provide a proper key function:

```
output.sort(key=lambda s: input.find(s))
```

Which can also be written as simply:

```
output.sort(key=input.find)
```

The expression `a - b` returns a negative value if `a < b`, `0` if `a == b` and a positive value if `a > b`. So this means that your code is sorting `output` according to where the elements it contains are found in `input`.

So the `key` function is to just lookup where the substring is in `input`.

---

To use `cmp_to_key` you'd do this instead:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

output.sort(key=cmp_to_key(lambda s1, s2: input.find(s1) - input.find(s2)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for ages with no answer I could wrap my head around.

Comment: @MPatel glad to help. Anyway StackOverflow has already two ways to thank an other users: upvotes and acceptance of an answer. You should consider using them in addition or instead of writing a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

*Both list.sort() and sorted() have a key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.*

Thus,

```
output.sort(key=lambda s: input.find(s[0])-input.find(s[1]))
```

Comment: That won't perform the correct sort. Presumably `s` is a string, so for string `s` your lambda returns the difference between the index of character `s[0]` and the index of character `s[1]` as the key. If neither char is found in `input` that will give a result of zero, since both `.find` calls will return -1. And it will crash with an IndexError if `s` consists of a single char. The proper key function is given in Bakuriu's answer: `lambda s: input.find(s)`.

Comment: I see. The type of the elements in 'output' wasn't quite clear in the question. But it should address the reported error.